# need a Sample JSON parser in objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, parsing, json

I want to know to parse a json object in objective C. I got the JSON object by loading a url. Can u please tell me how to do it or any samples or any reference.

The following is the sample json.

```
{
"name":"WFNX",
"now":
     {
     "id":"17749528",
     "song":"Back Down South",
     "artist":"Kings Of Leon"
     },
"desc":"101.7 - True Alternative",
"audiostream":"http:\/\/www.streamaudio.com\/stations   \/asx\/wfnx_fm.asx",
"genre":"Rock",
"tz":"EST",
"id":"17880",
"yes":"station"
}
```

Comment: You can refer this link also
http://cocoawithlove.com/2011/05/classes-for-fetching-and-parsing-xml-or.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Checkout this JSON framework for Objective-C on [code.google.com](http://code.google.com/p/json-framework/) or on [Github](http://stig.github.com/json-framework/).

It is pretty straightforward to use.  You instantiate your SBJSON object then call *objectWithString* with your buffer:

```
SBJSON * parser = [[SBJSON alloc] init];
NSString * buffer = @"{"name":"WFNX"}";
NSError* error = NULL;
// the type of json will depend on the JSON data in buffer, in this case, it will be 
// and NSDictionary with one key/value pair "name"->"WFNX"
id json = [parser objectWithString:buffer error:&error];
```

Comment: @rockey no problems :) If the answer is useful you can upvote it or select it as your "accepted answer". Good luck.

Answer (score 5):

There are a few out there, see:

http://code.google.com/p/json-framework/
http://github.com/schwa/TouchJSON

for a big list:

http://www.json.org/

is a great reference site for JSON

Answer (score 0):

I'm using YAJLiOS parser,not bad and compatable with ARC, here's documentation

http://gabriel.github.com/yajl-objc/

and parser itself on github

https://github.com/gabriel/yajl-objc

ex.

```
   NSData *JSONData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:@"someJson.json"];
   NSDictionary *JSONDictionary = [tempContainer yajl_JSON];
```

and getting objects by objectForKey method or valueFoKey method if you need an array